# How to divide large factorial numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial

In my discrete mathmatics class, I am tasked with dividing a large factorial number by another large factorial number. The numbers are too big to use calculators. How can I do this problem?

$$\frac{640!}{20!\,620!} = ?$$

Comment: Well, there's a lot of cancelling you can do.  $\frac {640!}{620!}=621\times 622\times \cdots \times 640$, to get you started.

Comment: You may use logarithms afterwards if your calculator still can't compute the fraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to see how this works with smaller numbers. Consider $\frac{10!}{7!\,3!}$. We can cancel like this:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{(7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1)(3\cdot 2\cdot 1)} &= \frac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot \not7\cdot \not6\cdot \not5\cdot \not4\cdot \not3\cdot \not2\cdot \not1}{(\not7\cdot \not6\cdot \not5\cdot \not4\cdot \not3\cdot \not2\cdot \not1)(3\cdot 2\cdot 1)}\\
&= \frac{10 \cdot9\cdot8}{3\cdot2\cdot1}
\end{align}$$

This last expression is much easier to deal with. We can carry out more cancellations as we find them, and end up with an integer at the end. A more compact way of writing this out is this:

$$\frac{10!}{7!\,3!}=\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7!}{7!\,3!}=\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot\not{7!}}{\not{7!}\,3!}=\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8}{3!}$$

In your case, we can write:

$$\frac{640!}{20!\,620!}=\frac{640\cdot 639\cdots621\cdot620!}{20!\,620!}=\frac{640\cdot 639\cdots621}{20!}$$

You can keep canceling from here, as each number on the bottom has a multiple on top, or you could probably use your calculator at this step. The number $20!$ is not too big for most calculators to handle, at $19$ digits. The numerator is $56$ digits, which is getting  bit unwieldy... Cancellation is better.

Answer (score 1):

This is the binomial coefficient
$$\binom{640}{20}.$$
It equals
$$\frac{640\times639\times638\times\cdots\times623\times622\times621}{20\times19\times18\times\cdots\times3\times2\times1}$$
and one can cancel everything in the denominator from the numerator.
It will leave a reasonably practical multiplication.
I'd prefer not to have to actually do it. $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the calculator to do all the simplifications but the get the result you must do something by hand because the result is anyway too big to be memorized by a calculator, $38$ digits $$40\,477\,522\,598\,018\,531\,284\,007\,399\,717\,734\,668\,000$$

I have   simplified for you

$$\small\frac{640\cdot  639\cdot  638\cdot  637\cdot  636\cdot  635\cdot  634\cdot  633\cdot  632\cdot  631\cdot  630\cdot  629\cdot  628\cdot  \
627\cdot  626\cdot  625\cdot  624\cdot  623\cdot  622\cdot  621}{{20\cdot  19\cdot  18\cdot  17\cdot  16\cdot  15\cdot  14\cdot  13\cdot  12\cdot  11\cdot  10\cdot  9\cdot  8\cdot  7\cdot  6\cdot  5\cdot  4\cdot  3\cdot  2}}$$

you need just to compute with a calculator

$$a =  23\times 311\times 89\times 13\times 313\times 7\times 10\\
b = 33\times 157\times 37\times 7\times 631\times 79\times 71\times 10\\
c = 633\times 634\times 127\times 106\times 58\times 15$$
and finally by hand
$$a\cdot b\cdot c=40\,477\,522\,598\,018\,531\,284\,007\,399\,717\,734\,668\,000$$

Hope this can help